# Why is saving a vector element in a local variable so much faster?

Tags: c++, stdvector

When running leetcode, I noticed that this code:

```
while(row !=size && col >= 0)
        {
            int curr = matrix[row][col];
            if (curr == target) return true;

            if (target > curr)
            {
                row++;
            }
            else
            {
                col--;
            }
        }
```

is much faster than the equivalent code (from 104 ms down to 64 ms):

```
while(row !=size && col >= 0)
        {
            
            if (matrix[row][col]== target) return true;

            if (target > matrix[row][col])
            {
                row++;
            }
            else
            {
                col--;
            }
        }
```

Why is it faster to save the vector element in a local variable?  Once a vector element is accessed, shouldn't it be put in the cache already, so you would get a cache hit either way?

Comment: Did you compile with optimisations enabled?  If not, the compiler will evaluate `matrix[row][col]` twice in the second example and that will cost you.

Comment: Create a [mcve]